# In hadoop Map-Reduce, how to know end of map task or end of file for mapper

Tags: hadoop2

In a MapReduce job, mapper starts processing from the 1st line of the input file till the n'th line. I need to find out when our mapper starts processing the n'th line. I want to perform some action, when the mapper is executing the last line of input. So, I want an indication to the mapper for the last line of the file. Is there any method in Hadoop library which can achieve this?

I am using Hadoop 2.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're trying to perform some cleanup in the mapper before the task is destroyed. Is that correct? If so, would overriding org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper#cleanup(Context) suffice?

Comment: Yes every time when mapper will called then it will update one variable.let'say say I m finding local maximum value from each mapper.and giving to reducer..so for find local maximum at mapper side I have to update local maximum variable value each time.and when mapper will read last time then mapper will give local maximum value to reducer....so here I m giving only one value to reducer...for that I have to know Las file of line at each mapper

Comment: I saw clean up .but I am confused how we can use clean up...how calling will perform....and can I use clean up in my above requirement

Comment: cleanup is called automatically at the end of each successful map task. You can use context.write(key, value) to emit a value from the cleanup method and it will be sent to reducers.

Comment: protected void cleanup( Context context) throws IOException{
 try{
 System.out.println("inside clean up methode ");
 context.write(new Text("hii"), new IntWritable(11111));  
 }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}  
}